# Regex to find specific dots and escape them

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string "**#letme.doit.now .emiter #another.test #plus.test.**"
I need to find all dots that has something after, which are in those parts that starts with # and don't have white spaces.
Actually the match has to hold dot 1, 2, 4 and 5. All other dots don't have to be there in the match.

Comment: do you search for: /\S\.\S/ ?

Comment: would all non-matches be like .emiter here: \s\.\S+ ? In other words, all of them a preceded by a space? Or can they be like " .emiter.something.more" ?

Comment: @inger, no, if string starts with ".emiter #whatever.superb", 1st dot is not in the match also. If string is like your example: " .emiter.something.more" - there're no matches at all, as I need to match only those who has # at the beginnging (not at the beginning of the string, but at the word).

Comment: I was asking about _non-matches_ , not _matches_. My point was, if a non-matched dot would always be preceded by space, then one regexp replacement could be enough. You say it's not the case (so the dots before something & more above cannot be locally distinguished IMO); consequently you need 2 regexes - just like Rob W-s answer. Will you accept that one?

Comment: @inger, I am currently testing Rob W's solution, however already think I will accept it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find and escape the dots according to the requirements:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q9hLQ/

```
var string = "#letme.doit.now .emiter #another.test #plus.test.";
string = string.replace(/#\S+/g, function(full_match) {
    return full_match.replace(/\.(?!$)/g, '\\.');
});
// Output: #letme\.doit\.now .emiter #another\.test #plus\.test.
```

1. Find each consecutive `#` + non-whitespace characters.
2. Inside these matches, replace all dots, except for the dot at the end, with a backslash+dot.

Comment: "that starts with #" : /(#[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.(\S)/g

Comment: @user1150525 Title: "find specific dots and escape them".

Comment: It seems like i oversaw (dt.: übersehen?) something.

Comment: @RobW, your approach seems suits me very well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

For matching

```
"#letme.doit.now .emiter #another.test #plus.test.".match(/#[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.\w+)+/g)
```

Will return `["#letme.doit.now", "#another.test", "#plus.test"]`

For escape

```
"#letme.doit.now .emiter #another.test #plus.test.".replace(/(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.(\w)/g, '$1\\.$2')
```

Comment: no, it isn't. What about "# .something" ? you have to change [^\.] to \S

Comment: @user1150525, string that is "# .something" has to have no matches.